# Expose php file on a WordPress hosted site

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I just launched a WordPress site that has a form to allow users to select something they want to buy.  We are implementing a third-party shopping cart service that requires urls to be in very specific formats.  I want to retrieve the POSTed variables and then issue a redirect (basically a GET) to this third-party shopping cart.  I was going to just create a buy.php file that did just that- retrieve the POST variables and create the url.

The problem is that I don't know how to expose the buy.php page.  I keep getting routed to the 404.html page.

I figured I would create a new location that is before all of the others, but the server log complained about not being able to find the file.  Once I fixed that problem, the file wasn't touched, but the request was handled by the 404 page.

The server is running Nginx.  Config is below:

```
server {

  access_log off;
  error_log  /var/log/site-name.com_error_log;
  root /var/www/vhosts/site-name.com/httpdocs;

  listen    80;
  listen    443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /XXX.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /XXX-cert.key;

  # server_name   www.site-name.com ;
  server_name   site-name.com ;

  # i can't get this /buy to work
  location /buy/ {
    #  what do I put here to be used in a form Action
  }

  location / {
    root   /var/www/vhosts/site-name.com/httpdocs;
    index  index.html index.php index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

   location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
  }

  location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;


#      fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

    include fastcgi_params;
 }

# WordPress single site rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

   # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
        expires 365d; access_log off; log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, like where your php script is, why are you not setting the action on your form, etc.  In addition are you implementing your own shopping cart?

Comment: I added more info above.  We are using a third-party shopping cart provider.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  I just needed a rewrite statement for that section, and another to test it:

```
location /buy {
     rewrite / /wp-content/themes/uncode-child/buy/index.php;
}

location /test {
     rewrite / /wp-content/themes/uncode-child/buy/test.html;
}
```